# What's wrong with AQL request?

Tags: json, http, curl, arangodb, aql

I need to check if DB have specified IP address.

This request:

```
echo {"query" : "FOR v in visitors return v.guid"} | curl -X POST --data-binary @- --dump - http://localhost:8529/_db/otest/_api/cursor
```

Is return my next result:

```
{"result":["7478d52d-af3e-4a83-9791-4e827dfe9059",null,"8d324b9e-7376-4977-9976-1606045c7086"],"hasMore":false,"cached":false,"extra":{"stats":{"writesExecuted":0,"writesIgnored":0,"scannedFull":3,"scannedIndex":0,"filtered":0,"executionTime":0},"warnings":[]},"error":false,"code":201}
```

But when I am sending request with `FILTER` like:

```
echo {"query" : "FOR v in visitors FILTER v.ip == "127.0.0.1" return v.guid"} | curl -X POST --data-binary @- --dump - http://localhost:8529/_db/otest/_api/cursor
```

I am getting error:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: ArangoDB
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 73

{"error":true,"errorMessage":"expecting comma","code":400,"errorNum":600}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Also how I can get result without metadata of request like: `..."hasMore":false,"cached":...`

Comment: Did the answer work for you? if yes, can you mark it 'accepted'? If not, whats missing?

Answer (score 2):

If you use quotes inside of the AQL query, you either need to use single quotes, or escape them so your json post document remains valid.

You can easily revalidate your json using i.e. [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
cat <<EOF |jq . 
{"query" : "FOR v in visitors FILTER v.ip == "127.0.0.1" return v.guid"}
EOF

parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 56
```

and fix it by i.e. replacing the inner double quotes by single quotes:

```
cat <<EOF |jq . 
{"query" : "FOR v in visitors FILTER v.ip == '127.0.0.1' return v.guid"}
EOF

{
  "query": "FOR v in visitors FILTER v.ip == '127.0.0.1' return v.guid"
}
```

or escaping the double quotes using `\`:

```
cat <<EOF |jq . 
{"query" : "FOR v in visitors FILTER v.ip == \"127.0.0.1\" return v.guid"}
EOF
{
  "query": "FOR v in visitors FILTER v.ip == \"127.0.0.1\" return v.guid"
}
```

Note that I'm using here documents (`<<EOF`) in bash, so another level of quoting can be avoided.

Comment: Just to clarify what @dothebart said: the error is not in AQL but in the JSON request body. Because JSON strings are always wrapped in double quotes you need to escape any double quotes you want to use inside the string.